# why can java not find my .jar file

Tags: java, jar, classnotfoundexception

I have the jtattoo jar in a forlder i created called lib in my java project but this line throws a ClassNotFoundException

```
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("src\\lib\\JTattoo-1.6.10.jar\\com.jtattoo.plaf.hifi.HiFiLookAndFeel");
```

Comment: You're using a relative path. Change it into an absolute path.

Comment: i have to turn this in to my teacher though, that wont work right??

Comment: I don't understand what you said in your last comment.

Comment: if i use the absolute path which is C:\Users\nic\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Golf Database real\src\lib\JTattoo-1.6.10.jar, ....it will work on my computer but it wont work on my teachers computer

Comment: Absolute paths start with `/` or, in case of Windows, C:\\, D:\\ or similar. Your code doesn't seem to be like that.

Answer (score 1):

Read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#setLookAndFeel%28java.lang.String%29):

> public static void setLookAndFeel(String **className**)
>                              throws ClassNotFoundException,
>                                     InstantiationException,
>                                     IllegalAccessException,
>                                     UnsupportedLookAndFeelException
>
> Loads the LookAndFeel specified by the given **class name**, using the current thread's context class loader, and passes it to setLookAndFeel(LookAndFeel).
>
> Parameters:
>
> className - a string specifying the **name of the class** that implements the look and feel

(emphasis mine)

A class name looks like this: `"java.lang.Integer"`, or `"java.util.List"`. What you're passing to the method is not a class name at all.

Classes are found by Java by having the jar containing them in the classpath:

```
java -cp path\to\the\jarfile.jar;path\to\the\otherJarfile.jar com.foo.bar.MyMainClass
```

Comment: yea i tried the class name which is com.jtattoo.plaf.hifi.HiFiLookAndFeel. i got the same error so i added the path thinking it might work...

Comment: *the same error*: **which** error? Don't you think reading the error would be a better strategy to fix it than trying random things?